# How to make vim recognize variables from files in the current directory or sub directories?

Tags: autocompletion, working-directory

I have recently been working on a web project and I would like my css files to recognize the classes and ids from the html files. Is there any way to make this work?

Edit:
So I use coc.nvim. By recognize I mean that I want like the variables and functions to be applicable(i.e auto completed) in the other files as well.

Comment: What do you mean by recognise? What does Vim currently do and how do you want it to behave differently?

Comment: To add to Rich question: I assume you mean for completion so you should also tell use if you use any tool to do the job (coc, ymc, etc...)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! As mentioned before, please add more context to your question. Please [edit] it to tell us more about what you're trying to solve. Thanks!

Comment: Have edited the question. So basically as I mentioned, I want coc.nvim to like recognize the class names from the html file when I am in the css file. Something like what vs code does.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are looking for this plugin - https://github.com/yaegassy/coc-html-css-support

This plugin recognizes the css file from the current workspace and provide them as a completion in your html file (or any other file you specify - https://github.com/yaegassy/coc-html-css-support#add-other-html-like-languages-example)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This answer would benefit greatly from an explanation of what the plugin is and how you think it will answer the question. Please [edit] to improve the answer.